# Is there a way to re-use a form component via inheritance?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

Dear Stackoverflow Users,

I haven't seen any examples regarding this question, but I should probably mention my plan first.

I have three different pages, that basically share many FormGroups. Their differences are basically minimal, maybe one or two FormControls. Of course, I could basically just copy paste the entire component and merely add the control I need, but I feel that it is a fairly impractical and messy solution. How would I properly approach this problem? And are any good resources regarding inheritance in Angular in general? The official page doesn't seem to make any mention from what I have seen in the hero course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I assumed, that it wasn't as simple as I thought it to be.
First, I create a FormBuilder class, that sets up all the controls that are shared between all the other forms I use. Now, any component that is extending the FormBuilder class is able to create a form like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Form } from '../form';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-invoices',
  templateUrl: './invoices.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./invoices.component.scss']
})
export class InvoicesComponent extends FormBuilder {

  constructor() { 
    super()

    this.createForm();
  }
}
```

So, the FormControls that I needed could be easily included by just adding

```
this.queryForm.addControl('newControl', new FormControl(''))
```

So the html code of the component required almost no changes whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with content projection.

Let's assume you have a FormGroup component with two inputs. This component will also have `ng-content` so that other components can inject their own html.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-form-group',
    template: `
        Type something : <input type="text"/> 
        Select something: <select> ... </select>
        Insert your own stuff: <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class FormGroupComponent {}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-form-group-radio',
    template: `
        <my-form-group>
             <input type="radio" name="myOption" value="1" />
             <input type="radio" name="myOption" value="2" />
        </my-form-group>
    `
})
export class FromGroupRadioComponent {}
```

In this way, you can reuse `FormGroupComponent` as many times as you want. You can create different kind of components and project different content.

Comment: While this seems like an interesting approach, it's not exactly what I needed, seeing problems with the field validation. I found a solution suiting myself somewhat more. I abstracted my Form into a seperate class. Every component using this particular class can simply build the form and add additional controls as desired. The changes on the HTML remain minimal, while the components remain very small and readable. I don't think that this is best practice either, but I also have to keep it as simple as possible for my co-workers for the time being, as I lack the expertise myself.